# Can inetAddress be used with inet6/IPv6?

Tags: java

Can inetAddress be used with inet6/IPv6?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Using the method [InetAddress.getByName( String name)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) for instance.

From the doc:

> *For host specified in literal IPv6 address, either the form defined in RFC 2732 or the literal IPv6 address format defined in RFC 2373 is accepted. IPv6 scoped addresses are also supported.*

See the [doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) for more details.

Comment: There is a typo I think: Should it not be InetAddress.getByName instead of InterAddress.getByName ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can using the [Inet6Address](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) subclass of [InetAddress](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html).